# WinForms Textbox Changing its margins?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, margin, multiline

So I've been working on cobbling together a game and decided I'd like to have a little program to show a file with each character replaced by its byte equivalent for working with coding saves and whatnot. Figured it'd a layup. Three hours later, I've been wracking my brain trying to figure this out.

When I load a small (or perhaps short is the better term) file it looks like the window on top. When I load a larger file, it looks like the window on the bottom.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16985121/Images/ViewAsBytes.PNG

That's 10pt Courier New, but it seems to happen with any font I try. There's always that extra column, and if there wasn't enough room for the column, it'd just squeeze in whatever it could in that space that it previously didn't use. I've tried tweaking all kinds of variables, as well as comparing the textbox before and after it adds the text from the file (which is read in just as bytes from a FileStream and then fed into a StringBuilder) but nothing seems to change even though something is clearly different.

I can think of a bunch of different workarounds for this, but now I'm just more interested in what TextBox thinks it's doing exactly than getting my program done. Anyone got any idea?

Here's the code that reads in the data and puts that to the textbox:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(files[0], FileMode.Open);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

int byteIn = stream.ReadByte();
while (byteIn != -1)
{
    sb.Append('[');

    if (byteIn < 100)
        sb.Append('0');
    if (byteIn < 10)
        sb.Append('0');

    sb.Append(byteIn.ToString());

    sb.Append(']');

    byteIn = stream.ReadByte();
}

txtView.Text = sb.ToString();

stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you set to the WordWrap property to True.  Set it to False, set Multiline to True and ScrollBars to Both.   Append Environment.NewLine to the string you generate, every 16 bytes is the norm for hex viewers.  Use byte.ToString("X2") to generate a hex string instead of a decimal string.

You now have a full scrollable view of the data, any amount is supported.  Allow the user to resize the window so she won't have to scroll horizontally.  Or just make it big enough.

Comment: So with wordwrap on this is just unavoidable?

Comment: Yes.  More to the point, this will lead you to making your program more usable.  A byte dumper (aka hex viewer) needs a well organized layout to avoid the user from getting lost really quickly.  You should display the info in a tabular manner, the canonical layout is [offset] [bytes values...] [ASCII conversion].  You cannot do this with wordwrap.

Comment: Oh well, I didn't want to make it to complicated because I just really need it for this one thing, but at least that mystery's solved. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Okay, earn your first 2 rep points at SO by closing your question.  Big check mark next to my post.